# Qt: How to prevent mouse events generation for tablet events

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, c++14

I have written a Qt widget which uses MouseEvents( by overriding `mousePressEvent` ) and TabletEvents (by overriding `tabletEvent`).
The tablet event handler is accepting all of the incomming events:

```
void StyleWidget::tabletEvent(QTabletEvent *event) {
    event->accept();
    ...
}
```

The problem is that, Qt generates mouseEvents for the tablet but I can not distinguish between the real mouse events and these tablet generated mouse event.

Is there a possibility to supress these mouseEvents?

Edit: The program is running under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

If the mouse events are generated by Qt itself, then you can do this in your `main()` function:

```
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_SynthesizeMouseForUnhandledTabletEvents, false);
```

There are some other similar attributes like the above:

```
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_SynthesizeMouseForUnhandledTouchEvents, false);
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_SynthesizeTouchForUnhandledMouseEvents, false);
```

But if the mouse events are generated by the operating system (Windows does that), then you need too live with them, and filter out the mouse events by `source()`:

```
void YourWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if(event->source() == Qt::MouseEventNotSynthesized) {
        // it is a real mouse event!
    }
    event->accept();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. The event source is `MouseEventNotSynthesized` even if I use the Stylus.

Comment: Sorry about that. Maybe the mouse events are generated in a way that Qt is unable to provide an accurate [Qt::MouseEventSource](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#MouseEventSource-enum) value. It may be also a [Qt bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-47910).